# length method to an array made from split method failed

Tags: java, string, split

I have this  :

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
String str = scan.nextLine(); 
String[]  stringArray = str.split(" "); 
int arrayLength = stringArray.length();
```

My problem is that I have an error about `length()` method. It cannot find symbol.

(My string certainly has spaces.)

Comment: please google it for finding array length in java

Answer (score 2):

Length is a property and not a function. So you need to remove the parenthesis and it work.
`int arrayLength = stringArray.length;`

When you say `length()`, it means you are calling a function and not a property.
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Form [JLS 10.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4)

> The length of the array is available using the field length

It should be:

```
int arrayLength = stringArray.length;
```

Comment: Look at the missing () when asking a field, compared to calling a method

Answer (score 0):

There is two thing to notice for beginners.

1) String is different than String[].

2)when getting length for these two its done differently.

For String (Class) its call to String Class Method() , As `Int stringLength = myString.length();`

For String [] (Array of Strings) its call to property, As `Int stringlength = mystring.length;`